# macOS logging to YYYY/MM/DD/system.log format?

Tags: macos, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I'd like my macOS write logs to files in a directory structure such as:
`/var/log/YYYY/MM/DD`. I was thinking `rsyslog` or `syslog-ng` would be helpful, but I haven't found any solutions online, and it appears like new macOS (Sierra, High Sierra) changed the logging architecture.

Have you guys tried customizing logging on your Macs?

Comment: Hi, you can do that by using macros in the filename of the syslog-ng destination: https://syslog-ng.com/documents/html/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-destinations-file.html

Comment: I know these tools can do this. The question I had: how to disable macOS normal logging mechanisms and how to direct all the logs to `rsyslog` or `syslog-ng`